# Fix first 3 dynamic columns

Tags: css, html-table

I have a table with row headings. I want to fix first 3 columns while horizontal scrolling. I have nearly 25 columns in this table.

```
       <table cellspacing="0" class="data border" id="question_grid" style="width:110%"> 
            <thead>
                <tr class="headings">
                  <th>Heading 1</th>
                  <th>Heading 2</th>
                  <th>Heading 3</th>
                  <th>Heading 4</th>
                  <th>Heading 5</th>
                </tr>
                <tr class="filter">
                  <th>Filter 1</th>
                  <th>Filter 2</th>
                  <th>Filter 3</th>
                  <th>Filter 4</th>
                  <th>Filter 5</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody id="trgrid">
               <tr id="grid_menu_2"> 
                  <td>Data 1</td>
                  <td>Data 2</td>
                  <td>Data 3</td>
                  <td>Data 4</td>
                  <td>Data 5</td>                
                </tr>
            </tbody>
     </table>
```

I tried using CSS but I don't know much about designing. I added `position:fixed` to first child of heading, filter and data rows.
Data rows will be multiple. I am using for loop to add those rows.

```
.headings th:first-child
{
    position: fixed;
    left: 5px;
    right:20px;
}

.filter th:first-child
{
    position: fixed;
    left: 5px;
    right:20px;    
}

.main_data_first
{
    position: fixed;
    left: 5px;
    right:20px;    
}
```

Comment: I don't think this is possible with pure css as it sort of ruins the table layout when you "remove" the columns from the table.  There are plenty of jquery plugins around to do it if you search for sticky table columns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found solution on http://datatables.net/ It uses jQuery.